# When I am trying to run mvn dependency:tree , I am getting : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/version/VersionConstraint

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sonatype, maven-dependency-plugin

I have no idea why this is happening. I tried deleting my m2 repository as well.

I tried with various versions of maven plugins(2.8) as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the complete stacktrace :

```
 Error injecting: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.internal.Maven3DependencyGraphBuilder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/version/VersionConstraint
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:1975)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods (InjectionPoint.java:766)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:683)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies 
          (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:181)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.version.VersionConstraint
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods (Class.java:1975)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredMethods (InjectionPoint.java:766)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:683)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
```

Comment: A maven plugin as dependency is simply wrong. Define a plugin in pluginManagement instead. Also show the command you have used and which JDK version, Maven version etc. you have used.

Comment: I don't need a maven plugin , so I removed it. I am using mvn dependency:tree , jdk 11.0.5 and maven 3.5.4

Comment: Which version of maven-dependency-plugin have you used cause it is not part of the error output ...which is usually logged out ... best would be to use `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree` to be sure to use the most recent version of the plugin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Maven version, at least to 3.0.x+ or 3.1.x+ [see here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound)

> This error is caused by Maven 3.1-alpha-1 migration from Sonatype
> Aether to Eclipse Aether (MNG-5354), which is an incompatible change
> for some plugins.

Other report [here](https://github.com/smoope/j2objc-maven-plugin/issues/1) claim to use Maven 3.3.0, so in any case, try with latest stable maven first (you can get it from [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi))

Side question: are you developing maven plugin? Usually you shouldn't declare dependencies on plugins in your pom.xml

Comment: I am not developing any maven plugin.. I just found it somewhere while I was searching online to resolve this issue

Comment: @GKr297 you have version mismatch between some of plugins you are using and maven runtime. Update to latest versions where possible

Answer (score 2):

You can solve by using an older version of the plugin as indicated by the [official page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound) recalled by the error log:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree
```